# How to animate viewflipper with two childs that have different heights

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, viewflipper, android-viewflipper

```
 <ViewFlipper
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:measureAllChildren="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">
    </RelativeLayout>

</ViewFlipper>
```

I have view flipper. And **animation** with changing that views working fine:

```
Animation slideDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
slideDown.setDuration(900);
Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
slideUp.setDuration(300);

mReceiverFlipper.setInAnimation(slideDown);
mReceiverFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideUp);
```

My problem is I can't animate my **flipperView** vertically. Since two child views have different height. And when I am flipping between `childViews` my `fipperView` resizing his height without `animation`.

> So, how can I animate flipperView when his size is changing?

Comment: Instead of putting direct child(RelativeLayout) with fix height into ViewFlipper take one more parent layout for each child.

Comment: @HareshChhelana how it will solve the problem? If I wrap my relativeLayout with another one what is going to change?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `android:animateLayoutChanges` attribute.

Add the attribute `android:animateLayoutChanges` on the ViewFlipper and set it to true.
(`<ViewFlipper android:animateLayoutChanges="true" ...`)

Then in your code, you need to add this line to enable the animation:

```
((ViewFlipper) findViewById(/* your viewflipper id here*/)).getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)
```

or in Kotlin:

```
findViewById<ViewFlipper>(/* your viewflipper id here*/).layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)
```

Source: https://proandroiddev.com/the-little-secret-of-android-animatelayoutchanges-e4caab2fddec